# Matplotlib using text instead of marker BUT can't be the best way to do it?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would just like to make sure I am on the right track here as this seems to be pretty cumbersome for Matplotlib. I want to use a label as a marker on a plot and have it working to some degree. It uses mathtext BUT I wonder if there isn't another way to do it?  Here is the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []

symbol = "AAPL"

x = range(5)
y = [5,10,12,15,11]

plt.plot(x,y,lw=2.5,color='r',linestyle='solid',marker=r"$ {} $".format(symbol),markersize=25)

plt.show()
```

Comment: what are you looking for? readability, optimization, less code to write... How do you want to improve your code?

Comment: using mathtext seems to be a cumbersome way to achieve what the code does. I want to have more control over the look of the text.

Comment: hi there  I'm looking to make the text substituting the marker more readable. Right now it's working BUT I seem to have little control over the font, size, background of the text.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you want, but below I have listed a couple of options that I am aware of for putting text into plots at specific locations (essentially what a marker is).

1) you can uses text/characters as markers through unicode. This is done by adding the unicode value within mathtext characters. E.g. take your example code; you can make the marker a unicode character by adding a 'u' before the string (unneeded in python 3) and then a '\u' and a 4 digit number. this will produce a unicode marker. Not all will work, as it depends on whether your system's font supports it. You can find a long list of them here: http://unicode-table.com/en/#latin-extended-a

```
plt.plot(x,y,lw=2.5,color='r',linestyle='solid',marker=u'$\u2609$',markersize=25)
```

\u2609 will produce a 'sun', i.e. a circle with a dot in its centre.

2) plt.text(...) using this function you can add text of your choice to the coordinate you specify.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text

I believe the coordinate will correspond to the bottom left corner of the text box, but you can play around with it to make absolutely sure if you want. E.g.

```
plt.text(x,y,'string',fontsize=18)
```

However, this must be done on individual points and will not plot a line over the data; it does not work like 'plot' although you could always brute force a line over the top with a subsequent line plot. This method is more of a pain and hardly optimal but it will do the job and is quite flecible if you want a string for a marker.

Comment: Hi @jdg10 thanks for the attempt but none will do what I want. The code will plot points but substitute labels ie AA for the markers. If you run it you will see what I mean. Although your approaches will work for simple cases ( that's what I gave as an example ) the real case I have working is hundreds of lines each of which has a label to show what it represents. So it's an implementation of a Tufte slope chart. I'm just trying to gain more control over the text that I am replacing the marker with. I'm using mathtext and I was hoping for an easier way.

Comment: @theakson [`plt.text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) really sounds like what you are looking for, [it has quite the list of possible options](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

Comment: sorry NOPE the text HAS to replace the marker. It's the best solution for my approach, the issue is that I can't seem to format it correctly. Using approaches that use a co ordinate system would not suit in the more complex case of 100 lines on one figure. I did look at it but NOPE.  If you run the code you will see what I am getting at. thanks for taking an interest though. I have looked at all the other solutions but this inline marker solution seems the best for me